# Post List by category and under custom taxonomy

Tags: categories, taxonomy, wp-list-pages

I am trying to listing posts from a single category with custom taxonomy and several sub custom taxonomies.

sub custom taxonomy "Knowledgebase"

- post KB 1
- post KB 2

sub custom taxonomy "Optimization "

- post OP 1

**but result is repeat post list not by custom taxonomy:**

sub custom taxonomy "Knowledgebase"

- post KB 1
- post KB 2
- post OP 1

sub custom taxonomy "Optimization"

- post KB 1
- post KB 2
- post OP 1

eg. code:

```
$taxonomies = get_terms(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => 'tutorial',
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                )
            );

    // Loop through categories
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

        // Display Taxonomy name
        echo '<h2 class="post-title">' . $taxonomy->name . '</h2>';
        echo '<div class="post-list">';

        // WP_Query arguments
        $args = array(
            'cat'           => 2, // wordpress category
            'terms'         => name,
            'orderby'       => 'term_order',
        );

        // The Query
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
        ?>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php

            } // End while
        } // End if
```

Comment: as per your shared code it seems like you do not closed `foreach` correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your post list is repeating because in your WP_Query args you are fetching posts just from the category with ID "2".

In order to get posts from custom taxonomies you need to use a tax_query inside your WP_Query. You can read more about tax_query here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

I would do the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    =>  2,//Your Wordpress category here
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tutorial',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    =>  $taxonomy->term_id,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hi giannisrig, 
Thx for time & help.
I've tried it, but the results remain the same.
Can you help me more?